# Question on Series Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Suppose we have the series 
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+2}{(n+1)\sqrt{n+3}}$$
and want to test for convergence. I have tried a number of things--ratio test, various comparison tests, Divergence Test, etc.--and can't seem to show that this series diverges. If someone could point me in the right direction on this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Short imprecise answer:  Look only at the highest ordered terms of the numerator and denominator.  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+2}{(n+1)\sqrt{n+3}}$ acts similarly to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n\sqrt{n}}$ which you should know more about.

Comment: @Matt.P Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Simply note that

$$\frac{n+2}{(n+1)\sqrt{n+3}}\sim \frac1{\sqrt n}$$

then refer to [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test).

Answer (score 0):

**hint:** Compare the series with $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried limit comparison with

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} ?$$

The series is divergent in comparison with a $p$ series with $ p<1$

Answer (score 0):

In other approach, I looked for the value of the sum accordance with the following:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+2}{(n+1)\sqrt{n+3}}=\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{n\sqrt{n+2}}=\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n\sqrt{n+2}}+\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n+2}}=$

$\sum\limits_{n=4}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n+2}}$

where $\sum\limits_{n=4}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}}=\zeta({\frac{1}{2}})-(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt3})\rightarrow \infty$

and $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n+2}}\lt \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow \zeta({\frac{3}{2}})-\frac{1}{2}\approx 2.1124$ 
$\big(\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function $\big)$

So the series is divergent.